# Is there an alternative to FB.Connect.createApplication() in Facebook's new Javascript SDK?

Tags: facebook

Facebook has deprecated their old Javascript SDK which had the FB.Connect.createApplication method ([documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/oldjavascript/FB.Connect.createApplication)). Does anyone know if similar functionality exists within their new Javascript SDK? It seems like they cut out a lot of methods :(

Note: there is Facebook.createApplication, but that is a part of FBJS, which can only be used within Facebook applications. I need to use this method in a web app that's completely separated from FB.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method doesn't exist in the new Javascript SDK. The new sdk doesn't have those specific methods anymore. Instead you will have to call the FB.Api method and pass the parameters to make a rest call or graph call. That being said, as far as anything I have come across the create application method is not in the Rest or Graph api. So in short, I think this is not supported at anymore. Hopefully, they will add this functionality back eventually.

Comment: One other thing. If you REALLY need this functionality, it is possible that the REST call exists, but that it isnt documented. I have found several undocumented rest calls by browsing through facebook's developer forums. Sometimes Facebook just doesnt keep their docs up to date.