# Using Facebook Registration plugin for multiple pages in the same domain

Tags: facebook

I have a website that functions as a directory for vendors. Each vendor has its own profile page with a unique   URL (similar to Facebook profiles). Is it possible for each profile page to have its own Facebook Registration plugin? For example, vendor_1 at http://www.example.com/vendor1 allows its customers to register via Facebook, and http://www.example.com/vendor2 has its own registration. Would I have to create a unique app_id for each profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each separate url you will need a separate app id.

Comment: Is it correct to assume one can not programatically create app ids?

Comment: I don't think this is allowed anymore.  Here's an old reference to it: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/oldjavascript/FB.Connect.createApplication/

Comment: There is some good posts about this on SO.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744223/is-there-an-alternative-to-fb-connect-createapplication-in-facebooks-new-java

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500318/how-to-register-a-facebook-application-via-api-php

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264080/create-a-facebook-application-programmatically

Comment: So there you go.  You're going to need a separate app id for each url, and you'll have to manually create each app.